# Linux utilities commands not working for particular user

Tags: centos, shell

We are using a centos 5 server. We are facing a strange problem where for a particular user, the basic linux utilities commands such as (ls,cp..) are not working. The shell gets hanged as we fire these commands. While the bash commands such as (echo, pwd) are working fine.

Please note: this behaviour is not present with other users on the same machine.

Comment: What does this users `$PATH` look like? Does it reference a strange location that doesn't really exist? Does it work if you specify the full path to the command?

Comment: might be related to the user beeing in an chroot environment

Comment: Also check the group memberships of the user as compared to other users.

Comment: @Sven: PATH looks correct and points to valid locations. Also I have tried the commands(ls) with full path but it is also hangs.

Comment: @Dennis: Doesn't seem a chroot issue.

Comment: Is this user's home directory on an NFS mount?

Comment: @JennyD: The group is same as compared to other users

Comment: Does `/bin/ping -n 127.0.0.1` work? Is there any unusual environment variable like for example `LD_PRELOAD` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Thanks kasperd.. I checked the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It contained a nfs location which is dead now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to kasperd (In Comments).

The issue was related to a dead path which was present in the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The issue got resolved once the environment variable was updated.

Thanks,
Praveen